# Circular button - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a circular button, but there is an error when I try to use ElevatedButton:

[image]

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Menu());

class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  const Menu({super.key});

  @override
  State<Menu> createState() => _MenuState();
}

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            ElevatedButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(
              Icons.train,
              size: 35,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        )  
    );
  }
}
```

I have also tried to create a FloatingActionButton, but it didn't worked.

Comment: Container is missing the child property over there. Like: `Container(child: ElevatedButton(...), )`

Comment: Just for the future, when you say "there is an error", please also include *the error*. Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Container provide `child` and you need to use `style` for decoration.

```dart
class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: ElevatedButton(
               style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
               ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(
                Icons.train,
                size: 35,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```